# Material-UI for React: cannot see changes when applying <ThemeProvider>

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I cannot see any change when applying "ThemeProvider" tag, even in a simple project as shown below.
There is no errors/warnings in the browser console (except for unused imports, but it fails even if I remove them all).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import MainBar from "./modules/MainBar";
import MainTemplate from "./style/MainTemplate";
import Palette from "./palette";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';


const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true
  },
  palette: {
    primary: purple,
    secondary: {
      main: "#f44336"
    }    
  }
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Button color="primary">BUTTON</Button>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any idea about it? Its almost like documentation example, and it doesn't work.
Thank you.

Comment: Which document you are referring? It don't match with official docs here - https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/advanced/

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Link: https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/
I tried to rebuild as a function, but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import `MuiThemeProvider` like,

```
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

And replace your code,

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Button color="primary">BUTTON</Button>
</ThemeProvider>
```

with this,

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Button color="primary">BUTTON</Button>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

[Ref](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/)

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you.
How it comes ThemeProvider doesn't works?

Comment: It works. But in the docs they use the ThemeProvider component, i cant find the  MuiThemeProvider. Someone knows where i can check on the docs the usage of MuiThemeProvider? Thanks!!

Comment: @JulioW. Check [this](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v0x/#where-should-i-start-in-a-migration)